# If the size of 2 subgroups of G are coprime then why is their intersection is trivial?

Tags: group-theory

Let H and K be subgroups of G, with size p and q respectively, where p and q are coprime, how can we show that H intersect K is {e} where e is the identity element in G

Comment: Hint: What structure does $H\cap K$ have?  Use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @Araon thanks for the tip, sorted now, much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$. It is also a subgroup of $K$. Now use Lagrange's Theorem.

More generally, if $H$ and $K$ are finite, then $|H\cap K|$ divides $\gcd(|H|,|K|)$. This is a simple corollary of that more general result.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$. Hence, by Lagrange's theorem, the size of $H \cap K$ divides $p$ and $q$. $(p,q) = 1 \implies H \cap K = \{e\}$

Answer (score 3):

LHS, as a bonus: try to solve a similar (dual) problem: Let H and K be subgroups of G, with *index* p and q respectively, where p and q are coprime, show that G=HK.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ \ $ If $\rm\:A,B,C\:$ have cardinality $\rm\:a,b,c\:$ then, using Lagrange's Theorem, we have
$\ $

\begin{array}{ccc}
              \rm A \:\subset\: B\cap C & \Rightarrow &\rm A \:\subset\: B,C \\
                   & \phantom{\sum} & \Downarrow  \\
                   \rm a\ |\ gcd(b,c) & \Leftarrow &\rm\ a\ \ |\ \ b,\ c \\
          \end{array}
$\ $